# go https client leaks

Tags: https, go

I wrote simple https client program for tests. It should work in keep-alive mode and not keep-alive. And it leaks badly.. In keep-alive mode it leaks twice slower.

This is sample working program.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        fmt.Println("Usage: cl <url> <close>")
        return
    }
    url := os.Args[1]

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig:    &tls.Config{},
        DisableCompression: true,
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: time.Second}
    for {
        buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(`Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam 
                          eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam 
                          voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione 
                          voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci 
                          velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
                          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea 
                          commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae 
                          consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto 
                          odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas 
                          molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt 
                          mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. 
                          Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime 
                          placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam 
                          et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et 
                          molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus
                           maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.`))
        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        if os.Args[1] != "0" {
            req.Close = true
        }
        req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)
        fmt.Printf("Sending to %s: \n%s\n=================\n", url, string(buf.Bytes()))
        if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err, "\n")
            buf.Reset()
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Response: %s\n\n", resp.Status)
            resp.Body.Close()
            buf.Reset()
        }
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
    }

}
```

I'm creating new buffer every time because in real program this message is always new string.
Usage example: so https://youtube.com 1

So the question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is leaking? (also, pass the body to the Request constructor. No need to duplicate the body handling yourself)

Comment: passing body to constructor (as expected) didn't help, but thanks foradvice. I don't know what exactly is leaking. I tried pprof/heap but couldn't figure out what its output means, besides SYS constantly grows.

Comment: What do you mean by SYS? Does the RSS of your process continually increase? Are you using the current version of Go?

Comment: Sys: the total amount of memory (address space) requested from the OS. go version 1.4

Comment: @JimB I run this and the RSS seems to creep slowly up for me, perhaps he is referring to that.

Comment: @user918176, make sure you run it long enough to stabilize (rss will creep up as untouched pages are faulted in. That can take a while). I'm not seeing any leak here. user4162071, What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. I added FreeOSMemory() function on every iteration. Memory grows much slower, but it still grows.. like 1 mb an hour.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit windows? (32 should be precise, but maybe not as efficient?). If you can create a better self contained example, try the mailing list and see if someone can duplicate your results. 1MB over an hour could just as easily be from heap fragmentation vs a leak.

Comment: 64 bit. And one more thing. Creating custom request is MUCH more slower, than just client.Post(). Go disapoints more and more to be honest..

Comment: I don't know what you mean, because the first line in `client.Post` creates a new request. Please provide examples before making unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: I measured posts per sec using both methods. And http.Post() seems almost 2 times faster (~110 p/s vs ~70 p/s)

Comment: that doesn't demonstrate anything without code. If you have issues you want to resolve, the mailing list is a good place to discuss them. This isn't the proper forum.

Comment: You do have the code! It is in the question. This program started with 3mb and after night of work it takes 80 mb! And they say it is a system language. My cpp (boost::asio) version of this client never took more than 5 mb though it does much more work than this sample.

Comment: @user4162071 This discussion might have some tips for you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/AhtZS3OgGM4